# Unity chooses constructor with parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am registering a type like thus:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()
                .RegisterType<IActiveDirectoryUser, ADUser>();
```

The class ADUser contains 2 constructors, one parameterless, and one with a single parameter.  When the resolver goes to resolve it, it chooses the the one with parameters.  How do I tell it to use the parameterless contrustor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When registering the type, use `InjectionConstructor` to instruct Unity that it should use parameterless constructor:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IActiveDirectoryUser, ADUser>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

Since you are passing no types to `InjectionConstructor` constructor, Unity will know to use parameterless constructor when instantiating `ADUser` class.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate needed constructor with `[InjectionConstructor]`.

Comment: Is there another way? Violates separation of concerns, that class shouldn't be aware of Unity.

Comment: only thru attribute or you can create concrete instance and register it. for example IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer(); container.RegisterInstance<IActiveDirectoryUser>(new ADUser(5));